# Mouseover and Mouseout function jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I have this script:

```
$("#teaser ul.buttons li").mouseover(function()
    {
        $("a",this).animate({ left: '0' },350);
    }).mouseout(function()
    {

        $("a",this).animate({ left: '-11px' },350);
    });
```

But when i now hover over the a element. The mouseover and mouseout going continu. How can i change this script. That when i hover of the a element. That the mouseout launch when i hover off the element.

Comment: could you add some HTML code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is http://jsfiddle.net/BBUJ7/ what you are looking for? I changed the `mouseover` and `mouseout` to [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) since you mentioned hovering in the question and added `a {position:relative}` CSS rule.

Answer (score 10):

use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`

Answer (score 1):

Here you have html code:

```
<ul class="buttons">
                    <li>
                        <h2>
                            <a class="koeriersdiensten" href="pagina.html" title="Koeriersdiensten">Koeriersdiensten
                                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h2>
                            <a class="taxivervoer" href="pagina.html" title="Taxivervoer">Taxivervoer
                                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```